# Puzzle solving c++ code sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: c++, string, variables, int

I'm learning c++ and got interested by project euler programming puzzles. There is this puzzle where you need to find largest palindrome number made from two 3 digit numbers multiplication. Anyway, I managed to solve this puzzle BUT I noticed some weird behavior. Sometimes this code works and sometimes it displays some weird number. The code is written in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;

// Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

int main()
{

    string palindrome = "";
    string reversed;

    int64_t biggest;

    //reverse(palindrome.begin(), palindrome.end());
    //cout << palindrome << endl;

    for (int a = 999; a >= 100; a--){
        for (int b = 999; b >= 100; b--){
            palindrome = to_string(a*b);
            reverse(palindrome.begin(), palindrome.end());

            if (palindrome == to_string(a*b)){
                if (a*b > biggest) biggest = a*b;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << biggest;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any replies that help me to understand what's going on.

EDIT: the code might not be very efficient, but it should (in theory) do the work by brute force. It iterates through all *a* from 0 to 999, and *b* from 0 to 999 comparing a*b to variable "*biggest*". If a*b is greater than *biggest* then *biggest* is replaced by a*b.

Comment: You don't initialize `biggest`.  Did you compile with warnings enabled?

Comment: `999*999` has a result that exceeds what an `int` is guaranteed to be able to represent.  That sort of overflow gives undefined behaviour.  `biggest` is uninitialised, and the first thing done with it is to compare it with `a*b` - which also gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks for reply, I think they are enabled, I've seen warnings for unused variables. Build command looks like this: g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

Comment: So the problem is with "biggest" being uinitialised. That makes sense guys, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Peter isn't `int` guaranteed to be able to represent numbers up to `2^31-1` which is far from `999*999`?

Comment: @CyborgKombat - If you're getting warnings, fix them immediately.  That's the compiler telling you that your code is syntactically correct, but there are quality issues.

Comment: @LukaSsS - `int` will have the range you're describing in practice, but it's not guaranteed.  If somebody was pedantic, they could verify the assumption in practice with a `static_assert`.

Comment: @LukaSsS - the standard only requires that an `int` can represent values up to `32767`   (i.e. `2^15-1`).     Yes, your compiler may support a larger range, but not all compilers do that.  If you want a guaranteed max of (at least) `2^31-1` with all compilers then use `long`, not `int`.

Comment: `for (int b = 999; b >= a; b--)` should be faster. And you might even then stop earlier.